# Patching a function from within the same package is not patching

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am using the builtin unittest library. I am trying to test a function,in this example `a`, which calls function `b`. Both of these functions are at the top level of the package and are not class based functions. I have read the unittest documentation about where to patch and have found that you must use the patch against the function (`a`) importing the other function (`b`)and not patching the function itself (`b`), but all the answers and documentation seem to only reference class based functions.

I have the following heirarchy:

```
mypkg
|- __init__.py
|- a.py
|- b.py
|- test
  |- __init__.py
  |- test_a.py
```

top level `__init__.py`:

```
from .a import a
from .b import b
__all__ = ['a','b']
```

a.py:

```
import .b import b

def a():
  ...
  functionB({"USERNAME": username, "OTHER": other})
```

b.py:

```
def b(**kwargs):
 // do stuff with kwargs like calling APIs etc
 // This function doesn't return anything
```

test_a.py:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from ..a import a

fake_return_value = "heythere"

class TestFunctionA(unittest.TestCase):
 @patch('mypkg.a.b', return_value=fake_return_value)
 # @patch('mympkg.b') # Doesn't work, does not override the original function
 def test_mytest(self, mocked_func):
   a()
   mocked_func.assert_called_once_with(stuff)
```

Running the above tests with the patch call that is uncommented leads to the test being ran and the original function being called, not the mock function.

What am I doing wrong here? I didn't think it would be this hard to unit test, I come from unit testing React apps, so this is a little frustrating but I assume user error. All the documentation and googling I've done so far seems that this should work, or at least the patch variant commented out above. Is this because of my package structure and trying to mock functions in the same package or?

Comment: I'm seeing a few syntax issues in your example code that make it hard to recreate your issue. Creating a ["minimal, *reproducible* example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will enable others on Stack Overflow to better help answer your question.

Comment: Edited, hopefully this helps, functionB's functionality I believe is abritrary

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your code yet, but the thing that always bites me in the ass when patching is trying to patch the right thing. You need to be sure you are patching the function or class where it is **used** not where it is declared. This distinction entirely depends on the import syntax you use (i.e. `from x import y` vs `import x.y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your top level `__init__.py` which contains code executed at **import time**.

**The statement `from .a import a` rebinds the name `a` from the *module* `a`, to the *function* `a`** contained within module `a`. As such, all invocations of `import mypkg.a` (e.g. the patch in your test module) will return the *function* `a` and not the *module*. That is why you get the error `AttributeError: function a does not have the attribute 'b'` mentioned in your comment on my last answer.

To patch module `a`'s usage of function `b`, your testing code needs to be able to import module `a`. There are a few ways you can do this.

- Remove `from .a import a` in your `__init__.py`.

  - You can still access the *module* `a` via `from mypkg import a` or `import mypkg.a`
  - You can still access the *function* `a` via `from mypkg.a import a` or `import mypkg.a.a`
- Rename the *function* `a` to something else.

Comment: oh my, ok, I will have to talk to team about why they wanted to have this __init__.py like this with the rebind. I assume it was for a purpose, thank you so much, i've been confused about this for days lol, you're a hero

Comment: :D You're welcome! Also, using such imports in the `__init__.py` allows you to customize the interface you present to users of your module. For example, [this project](https://github.com/jhale1805/multicounter) of mine uses [`__init__.py` imports](https://github.com/jhale1805/multicounter/blob/main/multicounter/__init__.py) to allows others to import my code via `from multicounter import MultiCounter`. Without those `__init__.py` imports, users of my module would have to call `from multicounter.multicounter import MultiCounter` which is unpleasantly repetitive.

Comment: Got it. So essentially just a barrel export file to rename/rebind for consumer use.  Wish patch could recognize this. I'm so used to jest now that having things like spyOn which you just import the module then you can tweak it or watch it however you want has spoiled me I guess

Answer (score 1):

##### NOTE: This answer addresses a [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72378519/3) of the question

The commented out `patch` is indeed the correct one to use since you are trying to patch `a`'s reference to `b`. It doesn't really matter if `b` is a class or a function since, like JavaScript, both are first-class objects in Python and are looked up and patched by `unittest.mock.patch` in the same way.

I suspect the issue in your more complex system has to do with one of the following errors in your example:

- `patch` should be imported as `from unittest.mock import patch`.
- The mocked `return_value` should be assigned within your test, not within the decorator.
- `stuff` isn't in the scope of your test class.

#### Working, Equivalent Example

Here's a working example of the system you describe:

- Two modules, `a` and `b`, each with a top-level function
- Module `a` invokes a function from `b`.
- You want to patch the function in `b` to test module `a` in isolation.

File Hierarchy:

```
mypkg
|- __init__.py    // empty
|- a.py
|- b.py
|- test
  |- __init__.py  // empty
  |- test_a.py
```

`b.py`

```py
def b():
  return "World!"
```

`a.py`

```py
from .b import b

def a():
  return "Hello " + b()
```

`test_a.py`

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from ..a import a

class TestFunctionA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a_no_mock(self):
        message = a()
        self.assertEqual(message, "Hello World!")

    @patch('mypkg.a.b')
    def test_mytest(self, mocked_func):
        mocked_func.return_value = "Stack Overflow!"
        message = a()
        self.assertEqual(message, "Hello Stack Overflow!")
        mocked_func.assert_called_once()
```

Running the tests from the folder *containing* `mypkg`

```
$ ls
mypkg
$ python -m unittest discover
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, a few things:
 - I changed my import of patch to match was you described instead (no effect)
 - the commented out patch produces: "AttributeError: function a does not have the attribute 'b'`
  - the top level __init__.py is not empty

Comment: the top level __init__.py looks something like this: 
```
from .b import b
from .a import a

__all__ = ['b', 'a']
```
Since comments are barely readable I will edit main post

Comment: Gotcha. That actually changes everything (reiterating the importance of the "minimal, *reproducible* example"). By including `from .a import a` in the `__init__.py` you are causing any import of `a` to get the *function* and not the *module*. Since this is a fundamentally different issue, I will post a new answer and edit the old one to point to your previous revision.

Comment: also sorry about the reproducible, I will remember that better for next time, I don't typically use stack much

Comment: No worries. I know it's hard to make a good, simple example of a complex problem, but it both helps you better isolate the exact issue causing your problem and makes a world of difference for those of us trying to help with zero knowledge of your underlying assumptions. Check out the article I linked earlier as it has lots of good advice for the personal debugging that goes into creating minimal, reproducible examples.